# $geoIntersect seems to limit Polygon query to 180° width, why?

Tags: mongodb, geospatial

I'm inserting a Point in a 2dsphere-indexed collection, and trying to find it within a Polygon:

```
c = db.foo;
c.ensureIndex({'value.geometry': '2dsphere'});
c.insert({value: {geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [0, 0]}}});
c.findOne({'value.geometry': {$geoWithin: {$geometry:
    {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-90,-90],[90,-90],[90,90],[-90,90],[-90,-90]]]}}}})
// Point is found
```

However, when I do the same with a Polygon whose width exceeds 180°, the Point is not found:

```
c = db.foo;
c.ensureIndex({'value.geometry': '2dsphere'});
c.insert({value: {geometry: {type: "Point", coordinates: [0, 0]}}});
c.findOne({'value.geometry': {$geoWithin: {$geometry:
    {"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-90.1,-90],[90.1,-90],[90.1,90],[-90.1,90],[-90.1,-90]]]}}}})
// no result -- why?
```

I could not find any information on this in the MongoDB manual. Why the limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with this, I came to the conclusion the drmirrors solution does not lead to the desired results: you would have to insert lots of points not just around the boundaries of the box, but also the inside of the box to really find the intersecting shapes.

As for whether this is intended behavior, the MongoDB docs actually state: "Any geometry specified with GeoJSON to $geoIntersects queries, must fit within a single hemisphere. MongoDB interprets geometries larger than half of the sphere as queries for the smaller of the complementary geometries."

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/geoIntersects/#op._S_geoIntersects

I resorted to disabling the filtering altogether for queries that include more than one hemisphere.

Comment: what do you mean by "disabling the filtering?"

Answer (score 2):

I guess that if your polygon exceeds 180 degrees of longitude, it might "close" the other way round the earth.  So point (0,0) is actually not inside your polygon anymore.  Point (180,0) probably is.  You could probably create the polygon you wanted by adding a few more points on the "front" part of the globe, like (0,-90) and (0,90).

Comment: That seems to be a reasonable explanation. I guess I'll have to divide the rectangle into two and query twice. However it would be good to know if this is a bug or a feature.

Comment: You certainly don't have to query twice, only add points to the polygon to make it non-ambiguous.  Note also that all of your points are on the poles, at +90/-90 degrees latitude, so the polygons are effectively bounded by only two points, the north pole and the south pole.  If you would instead define a few points along the edges of the  actual polygon you want (assuming this is not just an academic exercise for you), you should get exactly the result you want.  And yes, this is definitely expected and logical behaviour of the software, not a bug.